# Using context of a fragment within its innerclass in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have a fragment `SelectFileFragment` that has a innerclass`Test`. 
I need to use the context i.e. the activity that started the fragment `SelectFileFragment` in its innerclass`Test`.

I'm new to Kotlin so I want to know how I can get the context and then use in the inner class.

```
//there will be a few lines of code in java representing what i'm trying to achieve.

class FileSelectFragment : BaseFragment() {

public Context context;      //java


override fun onCreateView{
....
context = getActivity();   //java
....

}
class Test(){

private fun testMethod(){

context.getString(...);    //java

}

}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kotlin, a class must be explicitly declared `inner class` in order to use fields / methods from the outer class.

Comment: Alright. But how do I get context in the first place in Kotlin?

Comment: And saving it in a variable.

Comment: `context` is already a property made available to you (Kotlin rewrites `getContext()` as `context`), so you don't need to save it as a variable or do anything. You'll probably want to use `requireContext()` though if you want a non-null Context instance.

Comment: Now, I'm getting this error: **Constructor of inner class can be called only with receiver of containing class**

Comment: You can't create an inner class from outside of the outer class. That's true for both Kotlin and Java.

Answer (score 3):

Adding this answer to make it clear for you. The answer is same as what @ianhanniballake posted above.

Please find the complete code snippet below : If you this this answers your question, please mark @ianhanniballake post as the answer.

```
class FileSelectFragment : BaseFragment() {

inner class Test(){

    private fun testMethod(){
        context.getString(R.string.app_name);    //java
    }
}
```

}